# JSF confusing bean's properties with bean's methodes

Tags: java, jsf

I'm working on an application using HIBERNATE-SPRING-and JSF. 
when I put a commandButton on my jsf page, it doesn't redirect to the other jsf page and, I don't know why .. 
for exemple : 
 from my JSF page :

```xhtml
<f:view>
    <h:form id="mainForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <rich:scrollableDataTable id="clientTable" 
                value="#{clientBean.clients_list}" var="client" >
            <!-- The Scrolable data informations... -->
            </rich:scrollableDataTable>
            <h:commandButton value="Detail" 
                action="#{clientBean.ViewDetail}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

I created a ViewDetail Method in : ClientBean like this :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Scope("session")
@Component("clientBean")
public class ClientBean implements Serializable {
    //attributs
    public String ViewDetail() {
        //some code 
        return "detail";
    }
}
```

in faces config, I've got :

```xml
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>detail</from-outcome> 
        <to-view-id>/clients_details.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

but, when I run it , and I clik on "Detail" button , here is what i do not got anything, no errors,no warnings, nothing ..it just keeps on the same page, and seems to load something, but does not redirect at all (and it doesen't even go inside the ClientBean class..)

So .. 
after looking EVERYWHERE on the net, I 've tried that 
(on the jsf page )

     `<h:commandButton value="Detail">
     <f:param name="action" value ="#{clientBean.ViewDetail}"/>
     </h:commandButton>`
and here is what i got when I run it :

: /clients_liste.jsp(67,0) '#{clientBean.ViewDetail}' Property 'ViewDetail' not found on type com.last.web.ClientBean

Though, I diden't make any changes in my ClientBean, it's like he confuses attributes with methods ..

if any one could help please for one or the other problem :).. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Is it JSF 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: JSF 1.2 .. I still have the same probleme :/

Comment: `<f:param>` isn't the right way at all to specify component attributes. You shouldn't focus it on behaving troublesome. Please remove it from the question/title, it's only distracting readers from the true problem. It's more likely that you're performing business logic in getter behind `clients_list` instead of solely returning an already-prepared value. Is this true?